# Android Eclipse Fragment extension/conversion not working

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-fragments, fragment

I have a method called getFragmentByClass(Class clazz) as shown below:

```
public  Fragment getFragmentByClass(Class clazz) {
    Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(clazz.getName());
    if (fragment==null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    else
    {
        return fragment;
    }
}
```

I then get an error within another class with the call of

```
public FragmentX fragment() {
    return MainActivity.instance.getFragmentByClass(FragmentX.class);
}
```

that states

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from Fragment to FragmentX

which is why I originally has getFragmentByClass() set to a return of type FragmentX. FragmentX is defined as such:

```
public class FragmentY extends Fragment{
// FragmentY methods
}

public class FragmentX extends FragmentY{
// FragmentX methods
}
```

So FragmentX is a type of Fragment but when I am using this call of the getFragmentByClass(FragmentX.class), it clearly returns a value of Fragment rather than FragmentX and Java is not liking the fact that I am in a method of type FragmentX with a return of type Fragment even though FragmentX is of type Fragment.

I can't change getFragmentByClass(Class clazz) to have a return type of FragmentX because it needs to be called by multiple classes which are all similar to FragmentX with their definitions too (e.g. FragmentY, FragmentZ, etc.). Another problem with making getFragmentByClass(Class clazz) have a return type of FragmentX is that once fragment is redefined as type FragmentX, getSupportFragmentManager() and .findFragmentByTag() both will not work for type FragmentX.

I am working with Android Eclipse but this does not seem like an issue with Fragment. It seems like a general Java issue that should be allowed but isn't for some reason. If its something so simple as to call a super() or a simple method, then please let me know.

Any and all help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: have you checked out that both Fragments the imports in the classes are of the same type? (as maybe in one you are importing the support Fragment and in the other you are importing the normal Fragment)

Comment: @Raykud in neither of the classes are the importing either the support Fragment or normal Fragment. The only class that imports a type of Fragment is FragmentY which servers as the base for the other fragments. FragmentY imports android.app.Fragment and then FragmentX extends FragmentY does not import any other type of Fragment

Comment: getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(clazz.getName()); that returns a supportFragment and you mention that FragmentX which extends from FragmentY and FragmentY extends from android.app.Fragment thats why you are getting that error... all you have to do is either change the "getSupportFragmentManager" for "getFragmentManager" or change the "android.app.Fragment" for "android.support.v4.app.Fragment"

Comment: @Raykud That actually fixed another problem that I was going to deal with later on so thank you very much! :D It did not fix the MainActivity.instance.getFragmentByClass(...) issue at first but when I went into that source, Eclipse offered the ability to cast the return of the Fragment to a FragmentX which it liked since I had set it so that it was using the support.v4.app.Fragment. Thank you very much my friend! This error has been fixed finally! :D